# LEETCODE 202 HAPPY NUMBER (PYTHON)

Tags: numbers, happy

```
class Solution:
    def isHappy(self, n: int) -> bool:
        visit = set()
        def happy(n):
            temp = n
            n = 0
            for i in str(temp):
                n += int(i)**2
            if n == 1:
                return True
            elif n in visit:
                return False
            else: 
                visit.add(n)
                happy(n)

        return happy(n)
```

hello guys.

input is 19

n will be 100 > 82 > 68 > 1

but result is False

can somebody explain why?

Answer (score 1):

End of the `happy()` function:

```
else:
    visit.add(n)
    return happy(n)
```

You're discarding the result of calling `happy(n)`, you need to return that value.

Comment: Thank you for the answering. Can you give me a code that fixed the problem? I try to figure out by my self. But it is too difficult for me.

Comment: ```return happy(n)```

Comment: Edited the code snippet so that it shows the descibed solution.